# What natural numbers are not equal to the sum of the sum and the product of two natural numbers

Tags: number-theory

What natural numbers $n$ do **not** satisfy the equation

> $$n = (x+y)+xy$$

where $x$ and $y$ are both natural numbers?

Comment: Is $0$ a natural number?

Comment: The text we're using has natural numbers greater than 0, so no. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $xy +(x+y)= (x+1)(y+1)-1$

Answer (score 0):

If  0 is a natural number, then every $n$ can satisfied $n=x+y+xy$, since you can let $x=n,$ and $y=0$.

If 0 is not a natural number, notice that $x+y+xy=(x+1)(y+1)-1$, then the request $n$ can be, for example  3,5,7,9, $\cdots$, $2k+1$, $\cdots$; however, it contains other numbers, for example, 8,14,$\cdots$